# SVG patterns in Tilemill/Mapbox Studio

Tags: tilemill, mapnik, mapbox

I'm working on a project that requires custom styles for lines, similar to that in Mapbox's `line-pattern-file` [example](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-lines/), but I keep running into an issue where my custom line symbology looks suboptimal on high resolution displays. Ideally, I would use SVGs instead of PNGs for this, but it seems that only rasters are supported by Mapnik for styling lines.

Although my use case deals with lines, more generally, are there any best practices or tips for working with raster fills and patterns on high resolution displays?

[The documentation acknowledges](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/high-resolution-tiles/) this issue, but only briefly mentions that it's a good idea to create two versions of fills and patterns for this purpose. From my testing, creating a 2x version of pattern simply changes the scaling of the pattern and does not actually look higher resolution.

Comment: It seems that Mapnik actually does have support for SVG line patterns, but it's not documented https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/1010

Comment: Mapbox Studio supports SVG line patterns (sometimes) but Tilemill doesn't seem to. For some reason, some SVG line patterns cause Mapbox Studio to crash without any warning, and will not open until you manually comment out the line-pattern in the stylesheet.

Comment: Have you reached out to them directly about this?  I've been curious about this myself but haven't had a chance to post.